# zoom parts inside a div and focus it. (jQuery & CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a configurator - Let's say Bike configuration

- I need to display images for each part of the bike inside a div, with all joined properly so that it looks like a bike to end user.
- Now, when end user want to change some part (for example handlebar or seatpost) he clicks on it. Upon clicking that gets zoomed and gets displayed in that div along some part which is attached to it.

This is where the problem it, upon clicking the part, I am using CSS Zoom property to zoom the part. But as the div size is fixed with overflow hidden, sometimes the part gets hidden. But I want that part to be shown somewhat centered in the div.

Please help if you can provide some alternatives or any idea to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put some code here what you tried yet?

Comment: @BachchaSingh: sample code here:

` jQuery('.display-frame-inner').click(
        function(event) {
           jQuery(this).animate({ 'zoom': 2 }, 400);
           jQuery(this).animate({scrollLeft: event.pageX}, "slow"); // This where I need to scroll nearby to the part
           }
      )
});`

Comment: No, no ... put sample code in your question ... and make sure it is a working code snippet that reproduces the issue you have